# How am I meant to split the hot water tap so it can be used in two appliances?

Tags: plumbing

I want to run a dishwasher and washing machine off of this hot water tap. However, the only valves I can find are Garden Hose Thread, not NPT, which would imply it wouldn't be compatitable.

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Washing-Machine-Laundry-Splitter-Female/dp/B015X2C8M2/ref=sr_1_18?crid=2C6JX2HJ3XHI7&keywords=y+valve+washing+machine&qid=1695764164&sprefix=y+valve+washing+machin%2Caps%2C119&sr=8-18](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015X2C8M2)

Comment: Isn't the threading closest to the red handle a non-tapered thread (non-NPT) (perhaps garden hose thread) just like that to the right where the silver line is connected?

Comment: that is garden hose thread

Answer (score 2):

##### Way 1:

Cut the pipe beneath the box, shove one of these on and clamp it to the wall.

[image][image]

(*Opinion: expensive, and ugly to have this beneath the box*)

##### Way 2:

A this and a that

[image][image]

(*Opinion: Too much heavy stuff hanging off the valve's hose fitting and sticking way out of the wall.  Most likely to fail or break.  You could add an initial 90 degree hose elbow pointing downward so the heavy stuff is flat against the wall, but that's just another failure point and starts to look Rube Goldberg.*)

##### Way 3 (kind of cute):

Use the third entry hole to the box for the dishwasher. Tee off the pex and put a valve in the box.  Drill a 1/2 inch hole in the screw-off cover of the third hole to make a flange for the new pipe. Screw it back in and use a hose clamp beneath it to secure it tightly.

[image][image][image][image]

(*Opinion: My favorite.  Looks intentional, physically less prone to damage.*)

*All photos from http://homedepot.com*

Comment: Option 3 is definitely the way to go, but it does require the use of the proper tools. Unfortunately, there's about $100-$150 in tools to make this happen. Option 3b would be to use a push-to-connect Tee  and push-to-connect valve. They're probably twice the price of the crimp on versions, but don't require any tools except for a tube cutter which can be had for $10-20 at my local big-box store.

Comment: @freeman does that include an expander tool?  They cost more compared to a cheap crimper that's $20.    I think between a $20 tool as a learning experience and stepping stone to maybe better tools in future, vs using more expensive push-on now is a matter of style or comfort.    Whereas a $100 expander tool you're right, this project isn't the trigger for that.

Comment: Oh yeah, OP has PEX-A that does require an expander, not PEX-B that uses a crimp ring (either of the 2 varieties). The only expander I've seen is the $$$$ Milwaukee battery powered one. I'm sure there are some manual versions, but I didn't see one in my quick search of big orange's web site. Maybe there's a $20 version? I dunno... The cheapest PEX-B crimp tool I saw was ~$50, but that won't work for the OP.

Comment: Option 3 is still the best of the options (in your answers and the other existing ones at the time of writing) that I've seen.

Comment: I'm going to have to go with option 2. Another comment said that the hot water tap is GHT so I can use a Y splitter on amazon. 

I live in a rented apartment and the landlord gave me permission to install a portable dishwasher. I found a full size dishwasher that was on wheels. I really prefer not to do anything that the landlord can't easily undo after I move out. In addition, the taps sit above a sink tub so if they were to leak they would just drain into it.

Comment: Ok, so I think you should try a 90-degree garden hose adapter FIRST, pointing *down*, THEN the splitter and the 3/8 adapter.  That way it's all sticking less out of the wall, and and with less leverage on the initial coupling.

Answer (score 0):

Your dishwasher might not want the 3/4 hookup, but this plus some adapters might work: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-3-4-in-FHT-x-3-4-in-FHT-x-3-4-in-MHT-Brass-Wye-801639/300095982

(Edit to say that ‘garden hose thread’ might work as well, but keep your receipt!)

Answer (score 0):

Washing machine valves are usually "3/4 garden hose" size.  Get yourself a female to double male garden hose tee or wye, and an adapter to convert to 3/8" male compression.  Thread the wye onto the valve, then thread the adapter on one leg of the wye, and connect the dishwasher to that.  Connect your washing machine hose to the other leg of the wye.

https://www.brasscraft.com/products/fittings/brass-fittings/garden-hose-fittings/y-hose-fittings/ (if you *really* want to have valving on each leg you can use the one you linked)
https://www.brasscraft.com/product/38-in-o-d-comp-x-34-in-garden-hose-w-washer/